# Setting an HTML Checkbox to checked false via clicking on it or next to it

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I created a dropdown menu, which is activated and closed by setting display to block or none, depending on the state of a checkbox.

Everything is working as it is supposed to, but I want the menu to close when I click on the checkbox, which works by default or when I click anywhere else, which also works with my script.

BUT: I am not able to accomplish both. My script works fine, but then I am unable to close the menu by clicking on the checkboxes label.

```js
window.onclick = function(unchceck) {
  let button = document.getElementById("toggle_button");

  if (unchceck.target != button) {
    button.checked = false;
  }
}
```

```css
/* highly simplified version of the CSS, just to show the function */

.expM {
  display: none;
  }
#toggle_button {
  display: none
  }
#toggle_button:checked~.expM {
  display: block; 
  }
li {
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
  }
```

```html
<!-- my checkbox with a label, the checkbox is set to display: none -->
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="toggle_button">
<label for="toggle_button">
  <img id="menuBurger" src="https://picsum.photos/20"/>
</label>


<!-- simplyfied version of my menu -->
<ul class="expM">
  <li><a class="menuLink" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="menuLink" href="pages/GetStarted.html">Get Started</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried multiple solutions, but none  them worked. They resulted in me not being able to check the checkbox anymore or in the original premisse, that I was only able to achieve one of the two ways to uncheck the box.

Some things I tried were setting a cooldown/ timeout for the checkbox, which also did not work. I also tried to stop the function as soon, as `checked` = `false`, which worked neither.

You would help me a lot with a clean solution, making it possible to close the menu by clicking on the checkbox and by clicking anywhere on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is:

u click the checkbox lable -> the checkbox deactivates itself and the script activates it again because its checking if only the checkbox isnt clicked.

so use this to fix it:

```js
window.onclick = function(e) {
  let button = document.getElementById("toggle_button");
  let lable_img = document.getElementById("YOUR IMG ID HERE");

  if (e.target != lable_img && e.target != button) {
    button.checked = false;
  }
}
```

(add an id to your img and replace "YOUR IMG ID HERE" with the img id)

Comment: Your solution works perfectly fine, thank you!
I see my mistake now, I did handle the label as part of the checkbox, whilst js did differentiate the checkbox and the label.
So your solution is basicly mine, just adding the label to it, it is definitly the cleanest one, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Code for closing your "menu" for any click outside it, without disturbing the checkBox click event :

PS: your code was close but you neglected to deal with bubbles events

```js
window.addEventListener('click', ({target}) =>
  {
  // check for all possible elements
  if (!target.matches('#toggle_button, label[for="toggle_button"], #menuBurger'))
    document.querySelector('#toggle_button').checked = false;
  })
```

```css
#toggle_button,
#toggle_button:not(:checked) ~ .expM { 
  display: none; 
  }
li { 
  background-color: #464646; 
  }
```

```html
<!-- my checkbox with a label, the checkbox is set to display: none -->
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="toggle_button">
<label for="toggle_button">
  <img id="menuBurger" src="https://picsum.photos/20"/>
</label>


<!-- simplyfied version of my menu -->
<ul class="expM">
  <li><a class="menuLink" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="menuLink" href="pages/GetStarted.html">Get Started</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the 2nd and 3rd paragraph of my question, I am able to achieve that the menu either closes by clicking on the label or anywhere else, but not both.
"[...]the menu to close when I click on the checkbox, which works by default[...]
You simply deleted the JS so that you are only able to open and close it by clicking on the label or am I missing sth?

Comment: Your solution works perfectly fine, but it won't allow me to close the menu by clicking anywhere else on the screen. My problem was that I wanted to be able to do both, closing by clicking on it and clicking anywhere else. If you run the code with the script provided by Waradu you will see, what I mean. I guess it's simply hard to explain, what I mean exactly. Still a big thank you for taking the time to look into my problem and the multiple comments, I really appriciate that!

Comment: @Eric Ok, I just understood your strange way of phrasing a question. Why not just write that you want to close your menu when the user clicks outside of it?. I have updated my answer on this...

Comment: @Eric I have also optimized your css

Comment: Thank you! The your new function and css work exactly as I desired my function to work. Nice to see different solutions, there is allways something to learn from.
I phrased the question the way I did, since the tutorial, on how to ask your first question demanded me to list all these points, like what I tried, where exactly the problem occurred etc. I will write my question more direct next time, to make it clearer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the OP needs the menu to close/open according to the associated checkbox status (unchecked/checked), and in addition should the user click outside of the menu, then the default behavior is to uncheck the checkbox. The solution provided works for one or more menus, details are commented in the example.

```js
// Define a boolean flag.
let ignore = false;

// Collect all elements with the className of ".excluded" into a NodeList.
const excluded = document.querySelectorAll(".excluded");

/* 
For each ".excluded" element, bind each to the "mouseover" and "mouseout" 
events. Whenever the user's cursor is inside an ".excluded" element, the 
"ignore" flag is true, otherwise, if the cursor is outside of all "excluded" 
elements, the "ignore" flag is false. 
*/
excluded.forEach(exc => {
  exc.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    ignore = true;
  });
});

excluded.forEach(exc => {
  exc.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
    ignore = false;
  });
});

/* 
Bind the "click" event to the entire Document Object. Whenever the user 
clicks anything that isn't ".excluded", all checkboxes (.cbox) are 
collected into a NodeList and then unchecked. 
*/
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (!ignore) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".cbox").forEach(c => c.checked = false);
  }
});
```

```css
/* 
Optional. 
IMO a checkbox doesn't need to be visible＊ when the label serves as the
interface.
＊ Unless accessibility is a concern.
*/

.cbox {
  display: none
}

.icon {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}


/* 
"display: none" is still a viable option.
"visibility: hidden" is used instead so any surrounding elements will 
not shift. 
*/

.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #999
}


/* 
Pseudo-class ":checked" indicates when a checkbox or radio button is 
checked.
Adjacent combinator: "+" indicates what must occur immediately after the
selector that is to the left of a "+".
Summary: 
  - If a checkbox (.cbox) is checked (:checked)
  - and it is followed (+) by a label (.icon)
  - make the menu (.list) that follows (+) the label (.icon) visible 
*/

.cbox:checked+.icon+.list {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* 
This is the class given to any element that you need to exclude from 
being considered outside the menu and labels. 
An outline is added for demo purposes. 
*/

.excluded {
  width: max-content;
  max-height: min-content;
  outline: 3px red dashed;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
Match a checkbox "id" with a label "for" and they will be associated
with each other. If the label is clicked, the associated checkbox will
be checked or unchecked. 
It's important to keep in mind that each "id" MUST BE UNIQUE. But it is 
perfectly valid to have multiple labels with identical "for".
-->

<input id="c1" class="cbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="c1" class="icon excluded">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/">
  </label>
<menu class="list excluded">
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.com">Example</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
  </li>
</menu>

<input id="c2" class="cbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="c2" class="icon excluded">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/">
  </label>
<menu class="list excluded">
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.com">Example</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
  </li>
</menu>
```

Comment: Whilst your solution is definitly the most advanced and probably the most universal one, it is way to complex and to much code for the simple purpose.
Waradu provided a simple solution, which is basicly my script, with the label added as an seperate var, since I assumed js would treat the label the same way, as the checkbox, which wasn't the case.
Thank you very much for this detailed solution tho, it is really nice to see different solutions with completely different approaches for the same solution!